# Use Order By, and Group by on a Union result from 2 different columns

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sql-order-by, union

This My Table

```
ID      Value           SenderID     RecieverID
1       Hello There         2           7
2       etc etc             7           5
3       etc                 2           6
4       ee                  7           2
5       asdas               2           7
6       asdas               2           5
7       asdas               7           5
```

What I want is the value from either senderID or receiverID from all the rows in which a specific value let say 2 occurs in any of these 2 columns
I used this query

```
SELECT `SenderID` FROM `messages` WHERE `RecieverID` = 2
UNION
SELECT `ReceiverID` FROM `messages` WHERE `SenderID` = 2
```

Gives unique answer but in wrong order
like this

```
ReceiverID
7
6
5
```

I'm expecting the answer of this query to be ordered by ID DESC in which a specific sender or reciever id occures for example in my tables the msg between senderid 2 and reverid 7 is at id 5 and latest id btweend sendr2 and 6 is at id 3 and btweed sndr2 and 5 it is ID 7 sot the above answer should be sorted like this 5, 7, 6 instead of 7,6,5

Comment: You probably mean "5, 7, **6** instead of 7,6,5". So you want to order by most recent conversation?

Comment: Yeah it was a typo, Corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will order the sender/receiver IDs by their most recent conversation:

```sql
SELECT senderID -- , MAX(ID) as maxID -- uncomment to see maxID
FROM (
  SELECT ID, `SenderID` FROM `messages` WHERE `RecieverID` = 2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, `RecieverID` FROM `messages` WHERE `SenderID` = 2
) as sub
GROUP BY (SenderID)
ORDER BY MAX(ID) DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d7bc0/1

Comment: Wow, Awesome man you are awesome. this was me here trying hard and and using all the power my brain has since last four hours and couldn't find a solution which you gave in few mins thanks a lot. I Guess it was because i was sure Union all is not the right choice and was only testing with all the different thing with union

Comment: UNION isn't necessary. Mikes answer would also work with `ORDER BY MAX(ID) DESC` ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d7bc0/5)), but might be slower.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use inner query in a brackets in order to set what the order by refers to:

```
SELECT id, senderID from 
  (SELECT ID, `SenderID` FROM `messages` WHERE `RecieverID` = 2
   UNION
   SELECT ID, `RecieverID` as senderId FROM `messages` WHERE `SenderID` = 2
  ) as A
GROUP BY (SenderID)
order by ID ASC
```

Comment: Gives Error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Thanks It Worked but just a little question as i don't need ID from ID Column if I remove it from main(outer) Select will it effect the order ?? or not ??

Comment: you can remove it from the outer select

Comment: Sorry but After looking at it carefully I figured out it is not giving me desired result what i want is to select Value from senderid or reciever ID column in the order they first appear based on the sorted ID list.
But what this is doing is group by senderID using which selects random distinct senderids and then sort it

Comment: Try `ORDER BY MIN(ID)`. Don't select `id`. And use `UNION ALL`

Comment: But what i really need is to SELECT rows with MAX(ID), DISTINCT by SenderID FROM A(result of inner query in this answer)
How can i do it ??

Comment: @IrtzaShahan - please edit your question and add sample data + expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, IF(`SenderID` = 2,`RecieverID`,`SenderID`)
  FROM `messages`
 WHERE `RecieverID` = 2 OR `SenderID` = 2
 group by IF(`SenderID` = 2,`RecieverID`,`SenderID`)
 order by ID ASC
```

Comment: Not sure what the query does but its not giving me unique ID from SenderID and ReceiverID Column